# Using Spatial Analyst Classification in ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-engine

I tend to use ML classification of Spatial Analyst ToolBox in ArcGIS Engine, I wrote this sample code:

```
        ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
        IAoInitialize aoInit = new AoInitialize();
        esriLicenseStatus licStat = aoInit.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeEngine);
        licStat = aoInit.CheckOutExtension(esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeSpatialAnalyst);


        Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();

        gp.AddToolbox(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Spatial Analyst Tools.tbx");

        //--------------------------------------ENVI

        IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
        parameters.Add(inputtxt.Text);
        parameters.Add(sigtxt.Text);

        parameters.Add(outputtxt.Text);

        IGeoProcessorResult result;
        result = (IGeoProcessorResult)gp.Execute("MLClassify ", parameters, null);
```

but unfortunately the code stop with this error:

Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

I do not know how to handle it?

---

The value of LicStat is         licStat esriLicenseCheckedOut

The Line      result = (IGeoProcessorResult)gp.Execute("MLClassify ", parameters, null);
is throwing the non-helpful error

As you said ---ArcGis 10 way is different and as that tool is a python script I'm not sure you can use it that way.--- what is its solution?, what should i do now?

Comment: What is the value of licStat? The code will continue whether the license is checked out or not, see the eunum http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/esriLicenseStatus_Constants/004200000025000000/ for possible values. Which line is throwing the non-helpful error? You may need to step through in debug until it breaks and note which line has the error then use try..catch and see if the exception has any more helpful information.

Comment: The code you are referring to shows the ArcGis 9.3 or previous way of doing things in Spatial Analyst, the ArcGis 10 way is different and as that tool is a python script I'm not sure you can use it that way.